# How to align navigation with header

Tags: html, css

I know that this question has been answered plenty of times but I just can't find a solution to my problem. Any answers will be heavily appreciated as I'm trying to learn HTML and CSS for gymnasium.

My HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <!-- Page header/logo with our navigation  -->
            <h1>LINGSCARS</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">vehicles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
```

My CSS code

```
/* Importing fonts */
@font-face {
    font-family: butlerRegular;
    src: url(assets/font/Butler.woff);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: butlerLight;
    src: url(assets/font/Butler-Light.woff);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: butlerUltraLight;
    src: url(assets/font/Butler-UltraLight.woff);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: butlerBold;
    src: url(assets/font/Butler-Bold.woff);
    font-weight: bold;
}


body {
    margin: 0px;
}

.container {
}

/* Header */
header h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    color: black;
    display: inline;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    /* top right bottom left */
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

nav ul a {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

nav ul a:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}

/* Global tags */
h1 {
    font-family: butlerLight;
}

a {
    font-family: butlerLight;
}
```

I'm trying to align the header and nav on the same line as it's more aestheticaly pleasing and pretty much something I like for header/navigations.

Comment: `nav{display: inline!important;}`  like this?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini `!important` should be always the last resort. Using it casually will probably result in some kind of problems later in the coding process.

Comment: @Magiczne I used it because i think he have external css override it.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Since OP didn't show any external CSS, assuming it, and showing practices that can cause problems is not a good idea. It would be better if you tried to ask him for clarification is he using any external files.

Comment: if you use inspector you can see `nav{display:block;}` that's why i did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Guess @Simone Rossaini's answer worked. :-)

---

I think `flex` is the easiest solution for this.

```
header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

You can remove `display` property from `header  h1` and `float` property from `nav ul`.

[More about flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

Comment: This one worked as well and in my opinion, I think it works better than `nav{display:inline!important`;}

Comment: @Abow You should avoid using `nav{display: inline!important;}` its not a good practice to use `inline!important` - use `flex` as recemended in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
nav { 
 display: inline-block;
}
```